# Keep specific chars from a column of strings (Array[String, Int]) and apply algorithm per group

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, key-value-coding

I have a csv file containing values like Z1:A, Z2:B etc seperated by comma.
I want to:
1. create key-values with the number of frequencies for each key (already done this part)
2. re-write my array (or maybe tuple?) by keeping Zx (where x can be any integer) and throw away colon and everything followin (:A etc).

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qoja6y5b8z7u083/example_1.csv?dl=0) is my dummy file (for simplicity there are only Z1 and Z2).

So I load my cvs into a val

```
val example1 = sc.textFile("/Users/....../Spark_stack/example_1.csv")
```

then I execute map-reduce in order to get my desired outcome

```
val counts = example1.flatMap(line => line.split(",")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

I am not sure if `.collect` is necessary, but it is the only way to call entire rows or specific cells from my "table".

If I print that

```
counts.foreach(println)
```

I get:

```
scala> counts.foreach(println)
(Z1:C,5)
(Z1:E,3)
(Z1:A,10)
(Z2:B,2)
(Z2:A,2)
(Z1:D,4)
(Z2:C,1)
(Z1:B,24)
```

I want to rewrite that as:

```
(Z1,5)
(Z1,3)
(Z1,10)
(Z2,2)
(Z2,2)
(Z1,4)
(Z2,1)
(Z1,24)
```

One possible way to do this is by using `map` and `substring(0,2)`

```
scala> counts.map(x => (x._1.substring(0,2),x._2))
res25: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Z1,5), (Z1,3), (Z1,10), (Z2,2), (Z2,2), (Z1,4), (Z2,1), (Z1,24))
```

The problem here is than I might be given an some point so many Z's that their total number is greater than 9, for example Z15:A, or even Z123:D

Hence I need something more dynamic, that can tell where `:` is and `substring` until that point. My problem is that I don't know how to write it.

If I call:

```
scala> counts(1)._1.indexOfSlice(":")
res28: Int = 2
```

I get the posistion of `:`, hence I can apply like this:

```
scala> counts(1)._1.substring(0,counts(1)._1.indexOfSlice(":"))
res30: String = Z1
```

but I don;t know how to apply it to the entire counts, and not just in a single line. I even tried `foreach` but it dodn;t work.

Once I do this, I need to apply the following algorithm for each individual Z1, Z2 etc

somehow sort it in reverse order like this (works for a single Zx though, so I need to sort by 2nd column desc and my first column)

```
val sorted = counts.sortBy(_._2).reverse
```

and for each unique Zx apply this

```
var h =0
for (i <- 0 to (sorted.length-1) ) { if ( sorted(i)._2 >= i+1) { h = i+1;}}
```

in order to finally get for each Zx an integer (the var h from the for-loop above)

Sorry if it is too complicated, I am totally new to scala-spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
counts.map(x => (x._1.substring(0, x._1.indexOf(":")), x._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, absolutely do not use `collect`. This will force all your data back to your driver, which will overwhelm the machine--unless you don't have a lot of data in which case you could get by with conventional Scala collections anyway instead of Spark.

So let's instead use the `DataFrame` API and the `functions` library:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

sc.textFile("/Users/....../Spark_stack/example_1.csv")
  .toDF("label","count")
  .select(substring_index($"label", ":", 1).as("label"), $"count")
```

Here I transform the `RDD` into a `DataFrame` with columns `label` and `count` and then transform the `label` column using the library function `substring_index` to parse out what comes before the colon.

If you must use `RDD`s instead, then you can do what @sheunis suggests (though on an `RDD` and not on the result of a `collect`) or this:

```
sc.textFile("/Users/....../Spark_stack/example_1.csv").map {
    case (label, count) => (label.split(":").head, count)
}
```

Comment: You are 100% correct, I neglected to mention that I need to stick to RDD's and don't use dataframes. You are right though, using .collect solves 1 problem and causes lots more. I think I need to create an RDD where each row is `(Z1,(10,5,3,2,..))` and then apply my algorithm in this value (which is actually a list)

Comment: Updated the answer with how I would work with an `RDD` instead.